UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged not working until the DataGridTextColumn loses focus?
I'm trying to apply a binding for my datagrid so that I can capture the change to the cells as it happens (as the user types), but for some reason, I can only get to trigger the PropertyChanged event after the cell loses its focus. The same works flawlessly with a regular Textbox, meaning that the OnNameChanged and OnNameChanging events are triggered as soon as the key is down. I was also able to properly make it work with the datagrid by adding a custom column with a Textbox in it, however everything regarding tab navigation among all the cells in the DataGrid became really cumbersome after taking that approach.
Is there a way to make this work using the DataGridTextColumn?
<Grid x:Name="ContentArea">
    <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    
    <controls:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="0,50" ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.Parameters, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <controls:DataGrid.Columns>
            <controls:DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="" Width="40" Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" CanUserResize="False"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Parameter" Binding="{Binding Key, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value" Binding="{Binding Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
            <controls:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
        </controls:DataGrid.Columns>
    </controls:DataGrid>
</Grid>

using App1.Helpers;
using Windows.UI.ViewManagement;
using App1.ViewModels;
namespace App1;

public sealed partial class MainWindow : WindowEx
{
public MainViewModel? ViewModel { get; }
private Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue;
private UISettings settings;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    AppWindow.SetIcon(Path.Combine(AppContext.BaseDirectory, "Assets/WindowIcon.ico"));
    Content = null;
    Title = "AppDisplayName".GetLocalized();

    // Theme change code picked from https://github.com/microsoft/WinUI-Gallery/pull/1239
    dispatcherQueue = Microsoft.UI.Dispatching.DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
    settings = new UISettings();
    settings.ColorValuesChanged += Settings_ColorValuesChanged; // cannot use FrameworkElement.ActualThemeChanged event

    ViewModel = App.GetService<MainViewModel>();
}

// this handles updating the caption button colors correctly when indows system theme is changed
// while the app is open
private void Settings_ColorValuesChanged(UISettings sender, object args)
{
    // This calls comes off-thread, hence we will need to dispatch it to current app's thread
    dispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(() =>
    {
        TitleBarHelper.ApplySystemThemeToCaptionButtons();
    });
}
}

using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace App1.ViewModels;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
[ObservableProperty]
public string name;

[ObservableProperty]
public ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel> parameters;

public MainViewModel()
{
    Parameters = new ObservableCollection<ParameterViewModel>();
    var Parameter = new ParameterViewModel() { Key = "", Value = "", Description = ""};
    Parameter.PropertyChanged += Parameter_PropertyChanged;
    Parameter.PropertyChanging += Parameter_PropertyChanging;
    Parameters.Add(Parameter);
}

partial void OnNameChanged(string value)
{

}

partial void OnNameChanging(string value)
{

}

private void Parameter_PropertyChanged(object? sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{


}

private void Parameter_PropertyChanging(object? sender, PropertyChangingEventArgs e)
{


}    
}
public partial class ParameterViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
[ObservableProperty]
public string key;
[ObservableProperty]
public string value;
[ObservableProperty]
public string description;
}

I tried setting up the PropertyChanged event for each Parameter added to the ObservableCollection within the MainViewModel, along with implementing the OnKeyChanged event within the ParameterViewModel, the result was the same.

Never mind, after a bit of customizing and some additional work, we were able to get the Datagrid to work as we needed through custom columns with textboxes in them.
